# Alsa device repeating sound

Tags: c, alsa

When not providing new data buffer to playback device, it repeats previously given data buffer.
How to overcome this?

tried 
`snd_pcm_drop` and `snd_pcm_prepare`. but didn't helped.

in sw params i have used,
`snd_pcm_sw_params_set_start_threshold()` - to start playback when available frames are >= threshold value. and same as `snd_pcm_sw_params_set_stop_threshold()`.

any help will be appriciated.

i have seen `snd_pcm_sw_params_set_silence_threshold()` API, but dont know it will be helpful in this case or not.

Comment: how do you play data? using tinyplay?

Comment: Please show all your software parameters (`snd_pcm_sw_params_`*).

Comment: @Mr.32 reading and dumping a wav file.

Comment: Edit your question to show the actual values of those parameters (and the reason why you chose them).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to this fantastic post.
Fixed my issue.

http://www.spinics.net/linux/fedora/alsa-user/msg09906.html